# Unable to sync gradle on android studio 2.3.3 "failed to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Unable to sync gradle on android studio 2.3.3 "gradle project sync failed"
Here is the screenshot
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvBQl.jpg)

[my build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9psyI.jpg)

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

For each of those errors, click on "Install repository and sync project". Android Studio will automatically make the required changes to your gradle and install the required libraries.